# Elasticsearch Index Lifecycle Management based on index name

Tags: elasticsearch, lifecycle

Is it possible to set up ES [Index Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/index-lifecycle-management.html) to delete an index based on the name that has a date in it, i.e. `my_index_yyyy_MM_dd`, instead of index age?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no - ILM only supports age-based phase transitions, which is (to my knowledge) determined by the index `creation_date`.

To support pattern matching deletes, I'd recommend using the `delete_indices` action of Curator (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/delete_indices.html) with the appropriate filters for your use-case.